# Проверка объекта на наличие элементов внутри Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Есть выпадающий список из элементов. При нажатиии кнопки элементы объекта обрабатываются и я получаю определенный результат. Как сделать проверку на то, что если объект пустой, то делать редирект на другую страницу?

Код:

`html`:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
    <select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker sel" multiple data-live-search="true">
      {% for elem in elements %}
        <option id="val" value="{{elem}}">{{ elem }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

`python:`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', elements=elements) # получаю все элементы на странице
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        docs = request.form.getlist('sel') # сюда я получаю выбранные из списка элементы
        result = handler.dosomething(docs) # тут функция-обработчик
        return render_template('handler.html', result=result)       
    else:
        pass
```

Как сделать проверку, если `docs` пустой и нет выбранных элементов, то при нажатии кнопки делать редирект на другую страницу, например `error.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Нужно добавить

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', elements=elements) # получаю все элементы на странице
    elif request.method == 'POST':
      if len(docs)>0:
        docs = request.form.getlist('sel') # сюда я получаю выбранные из списка элементы
        result = handler.dosomething(docs) # тут функция-обработчик
        return render_template('handler.html', result=result)       
      else:
        return render_template('error.html')
```